# Getting document from Firestore to pun inside a Custom User profile but it returns null. Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hi there I'm having some trouble to retrieve data from Firestore;
I created a class User for getting all the information for my app.
User Class:

```
class User {
  String id;
  String displayName;
  String email;
  String pictureURL;
  String gender;
  DateTime dateOfBirth;

  User(fbauth.User user) {
    id = user.uid;
    displayName = user.displayName;
    email = user.email;
    pictureURL = user.photoURL;
    // setting info
    DocumentSnapshot resl = FirestoreUtil.read("AdditionalUserInfo", user.uid);
    gender = resl.data()['gender'];
    dateOfBirth = (resl.data()['date of birth'] as Timestamp).toDate();

  
    
      
    }
```

FirestoreUtils class:

```
class FirestoreUtil {
  static DocumentSnapshot read(String collection, String document) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection(collection)
    .doc(document)
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.exists){
        return snapshot;
      }else{
        print("no data found");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

After I return the snapshot, it gets null. But if I do this it prints out the correct values:

```
class FirestoreUtil {
  static DocumentSnapshot read(String collection, String document) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection(collection)
    .doc(document)
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.exists){
        print(snapshot.data);
      }else{
        print("no data found");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I tried literally everything but I couldn't figure out. Could someone help? I cannot imagine that is that hard to retrieve data inside a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably Future(async/await) problem. You are returning value inside Future, you can get this value inside another `then()` etc.

```
class FirestoreUtil {
  static DocumentSnapshot read(String collection, String document) async {
    // You can directly return it too without assigning it to result variable
    var result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection(collection)
    .doc(document)
    .get();

    return result;
  }
}
```

There is `data()` method for DocumentSnapshot, you can use `result.data()` and check if it's `null, isEmpty` etc.

I wrote this function with `async/await` but if you need `Future` and didn't want to wait operation to be finished, you can directly return

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collection).doc(document).get();
```

and you can use `then()` after you get the Future.